# Get all posts from a specific category

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

### The Situation

As some of you might already know from my previous questions, I'm currently developing a Blog-system.

This time, I'm stuck at getting all posts from a specific category, with their category.

### Database

Here are the SQL-commands to create the three required tables.

#### Post

```
create table Post(
    headline varchar(100),
    date datetime,
    content text,
    author int unsigned,
    public tinyint,
    type int,
    ID serial,
    Primary Key (ID),
)ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

`author` is the ID of the user who created the post, `public` determines if the post can be read from everyone or is just a draft and `type` determines if it's a blog-post (`0`) or something else.

#### Category

```
create table Kategorie(
    name varchar(30),
    short varchar(200),
    ID serial,
    Primary Key (name)
)ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

#### Post_Kategorie

```
create table Post_Kategorie(
    post_ID bigint unsigned,
    kategorie_ID bigint unsigned,
    Primary Key (post_ID, kategorie_ID),
    Foreign Key (post_ID) references Post(ID),
    Foreign Key (kategorie_ID) references Kategorie(ID)
)ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

### The Query

This is my current query to get all posts tagged with a specific category, which is determined by the category's ID:

```
SELECT Post.headline, Post.date, Post.ID,
  CONCAT(
    "[", GROUP_CONCAT('{"name":"',Kategorie.name,'","id":',Kategorie.ID,'}'), "]"
  ) as "categorys"
FROM Post
INNER JOIN Post_Kategorie
  ON Post.ID = Post_Kategorie.post_ID
INNER JOIN Kategorie
  ON Post_Kategorie.kategorie_ID = 2
WHERE Post.public = 1
  AND Post.type = 0
GROUP BY Post.headline, Post.date
ORDER BY Post.date DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

The query works for listing all posts tagged with a specific category, but the `categorys`-column gets mixed up as every listed post has all available category's (every category listed in the `Kategorie`-table).

I'm sure the problem lays in the `INNER JOIN`-condition, but I have no clue where. Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: It must be tedious to repeat the details all over again when posting a question related to a previous one. So I understand why you are referring us to your previous question. But don't you think it to be as tedious to jump between the questions to collect all the information necessary for getting the picture?

Comment: I added the details to this question, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there might be issues with your CONCAT function, as it mixes different types of quotation marks. I think `"["` and `"]"` should be respectively `'['` and `']'`.

Otherwise, the problem does seem to be with one of the joins. In particular, `INNER JOIN Kategorie` does not specify the joining condition, which, I think, should be `Post_Kategorie.Kategorie_ID = Kategorie.ID`.

There entire query should thus be something like this:

```
SELECT Post.headline, Post.date, Post.ID,
  CONCAT(
    "[", GROUP_CONCAT('{"name":"',Kategorie.name,'","id":',Kategorie.ID,'}'), "]"
  ) as "categorys"
FROM Post
INNER JOIN Post_Kategorie
  ON Post.ID = Post_Kategorie.post_ID
INNER JOIN Kategorie
  ON Post_Kategorie.Kategorie_ID = Kategorie.ID
WHERE Post.public = 1
  AND Post.type = 0
GROUP BY Post.headline, Post.date
HAVING MAX(CASE Post_Kategorie.kategorie_ID WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
ORDER BY Post.date DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

The `Post_Kategorie.kategorie_ID = 2` condition has been modified to a CASE expression and moved to the `HAVING` clause, and it is used together with the `MAX()` aggregate function. This works as follows:

- If a post is tagged with a tag or tags belonging to `Kategorie.ID = 2`, the CASE expression will return 1, and MAX will evaluate to 1 too. Consequently, all the group will be valid and remain in the output.
- If no tag the post is tagged with belongs to the said category, the CASE expression will never evaluate to 1, nor will MAX. As a result, the entire group will be discarded.

Comment: What you say makes sense, but the problem is, with your query, the only shown category's in the `categorys`-column are those, specified by the ID. I want it to contain all category's the post is tagged with.

Comment: @Lukas: Then probably you just need to remove the `Post_Kategorie.kategorie_ID = 2` condition.

Comment: But how do I specify the category? All the listed posts should belong to the specified category, but I want a full list of all the category's it's tagged with, too.

Comment: @Lukas: I think I've got it now. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Very nice, solved my problem. I'm going to read more on this but for the moment, big thanks to you.