# SELECT All Posts In A Certain Category

Tags: php

I indeed read this post ([Get all posts from a specific category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562178/get-all-posts-from-a-specific-category)) but it does not seem to apply to my situation.

My situation is that i have two tables as follows:

1/ table categories

```
category_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
lang_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (category_id),
UNIQUE (name)
         ) ENGINE = INNODB';
```

in which lang_id values are 1 (equivalent to English) and 2 (equivalent to Vietnamese) which is used for filtering by using $_SESSION['lid'].

```
category_id     lang_id         name
  1                 1           Arts and Entertainment
  2                 1           Computers
  3                 2           Nghệ thuật và Giải trí
  4                 2           Máy tính
```

2/ table posts:

```
    'CREATE TABLE posts (
    post_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    category_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,      
    lang_id TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    subject VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (post_id),
    INDEX (category_id),
    INDEX (lang_id),
    INDEX (user_id)
    ) ENGINE = MYISAM';
```

In which the category_id is the foreign key of the first table.

```
question_id     category_id     lang_id     user_id     subject
  1               1               1                1      arts  
  2               4               2                1      máy tính 
  3               5               1                1      business and money
```

I would like to select the posts in a certain category when we mouse-click on it. So, I run this query:

```
$q = "SELECT subject
FROM categories AS ca
INNER JOIN questions AS q
USING (category_id)
WHERE q.lang_id = {$_SESSION['lid']}  
GROUP BY ca.category_id

$r = mysqli_query($database_connect, $q)
if(mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {
    while ($subject = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
       echo '<ul>
        <li>'. $subject['subject']. '</li>
         </ul>';
}
```

But the result does not return as desired. For example, When I click on category 1 (Arts and Entertainment), the result returns two subjects (arts posted in category_id 1, business and money posted in category_id 5 ).

Can you help me to re-build the query, please? I really really got stuck here.

Comment: remove the GROUP BY ca.category_id clause

Comment: You're not checking for the selected category ID at all

Comment: if you are using posts table you have to join categories and posts, but I can see that you are joining categories and questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT categories.*, posts.* from posts left join posts on categories.category_id=posts.category_id where posts.lang_id = {$_SESSION['lid']} and posts.category_id={your given category}
```

Comment: Kudos, I removed the GROUP BY clause and added AND into the WHERE clause as per souvickcse's guide. This works well for me now.

Comment: If you like this answer please upvote and accept it as an answer.

Comment: I tried to upvote it but it requires 15 reputation. I just join the forum today, so I can not do it. How can I accept it as an answer, please? as this is the first time i use this forum....

Comment: Ok Do it later :) Welcome to stack overflow

Answer (score 2):

Add the category id in WHERE clause to select post of a given category

```
SELECT subject
FROM categories AS ca
INNER JOIN questions AS q
USING (category_id)
WHERE q.lang_id = {$_SESSION['lid']}  
AND ca.category_id = 1
```